# Google AdWords Campaign Budget History

Tags: google-ads-api

We are using Google AdWords API to retrieve current Campaigns, Allocated Cost, Budget Used and Conversions.

The problem is, Google always returns current Allocated Cost but I need to retrieve it date wise.

As an example, If I run a campaign on date 1 to 10 with Allocated Cost $100 and then on 11-20 with Allocated Cost $200. It returns me Allocated Cost as $200 however I need it as $100 for 1-10 and $200 for 11-20.

Any advice will be greatly helpful.

Thanks,
Chirag

Answer (score 3):

Budget amount is an 'Attribute' rather than a 'metric' in the AdWords data model. MaxCPC (bid amount), campaign names, etc. are all examples of attributes whereas Impressions, Clicks, Conversions, etc. are examples of metrics.

Unfortunately this means that you cannot retreive historic data on it through the normal reporting API - only the snapshot value as at the date you request the report (as you have discovered). It is only metrics that have the historic data available. You can check whether a data type is a metric or an attribute here:

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports

This means it will be very difficult (if not impossible) to get the historic data.

People regularly request this sort of thing on the [AdWords API forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adwords-api) but, to my knoweledge, they have never suggested they would ever provide it.

Comment: Just been looking into this very issue. Thanks for the followup. Frankly, it's completely unacceptable that Google doesn't let you retrieve this data... but that's not your fault.